How to use STRING_AGG function inside another STRING_AGG function in SQL Server
I have 3 tables with 1-n relations between them
CREATE TABLE Province
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    -- ...
)

CREATE TABLE District
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    ProvinceId BIGINT REFERENCES [Province](Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Ward
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    DistrictId BIGINT REFERENCES [District](Id)
)

I want to get detail data of a province which looks like this
{
    "id": 1,
    "province_name": "province name",
    "districts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "district_name": "district-1",
            "wards": [1,2,3]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "district_name": "district-2",
            "wards": [4,5]
        }
    ]
}

(1 province has many districts, 1 district has many wards)
Here's what I implemented using the STRING_AGG built-in function
select CONCAT(
    '{"id":"', p.[id], '"',
    ',"province_name":', p.ProvinceName,
    ',"districts":',
    CONCAT(
    '[{',
    STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT('"id":', CAST(po.Id AS VARCHAR(10)),
        ',"name":"', po.[Name],
        '","district_name":[', STRING_AGG(CAST(w.id AS VARCHAR(10)), ','), ']'), '},{'),
    '}]'),
    '}')
from 
    province p
left join 
    district d on d.provinceId = p.id
left join 
    ward w on w.districtId = d.id
where 
    p.id = @id

But SQL Server throws this exception:

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

I tried to search similar issue from this site, but couldn't find expect results.
How can I implement to get data from 3 1-n layers?

If only JSON_ARRAYAGG were available outside of Azure Preview.

What is driving the need to produce json here? This would be trivial, for example, if you had an api that could create the json after pulling the data from the database.

@topsail it needs to be get all data above as json and assign it to a response field. it's normal behavior in my project

Use FOR JSON instead of building the string manually. This ain't 2012. For pure arrays, you can use STRING_AGG

@siggemannen but the pure array is nested inside another array which I need to use aggregate function

What I'm saying is that it is very common to get the data from the database, serialize it as json, and then assign it to a response field. Why can this not be done? Saying you are doing it this way because you are doing it this way is not an answer. I have never built json manually like this in sql ... don't see why you are doing it here. Also, in any case, if did want to work with JSON in the database I would use JSON functions as suggested by siggemannen.

No, you don't. Did you read about FOR JSON? It has no problems creating arrays of objects

@siggemannen for json only return an array of result (it wraps a pari of [] outside the result which I didn't expect). my expect result is a json object, not a json array

You can use WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER to remove the array thing if you don't need it.

I beleive you then need to use JSON_QUERY or something to not cause escaping, but I can't demonstrate without sample code and data.

thanks @siggemannen for the WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER keyword. it removes unexpected array thing in my json string

@Thom just beat me, but anyway, here's the main concept:
CREATE TABLE Province
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
)

CREATE TABLE District
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    ProvinceId BIGINT
)

CREATE TABLE Ward
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    DistrictId BIGINT
)

insert into Province
values (1,'test')

insert into District
values  (1, 'distinct-1', 1)
,   (2, 'distinct-2', 1)

insert into Ward
values  (1, 'Ward1', 1)
,   (2, 'Ward2', 1)


select id, name
,   (
    select id, name
    , json_query((
        select '[' + string_agg(ID, ',') within group(order by ID) + ']'
        from Ward w
        where w.DistrictId = d.ID
    )) as wards
    from district d
    where d.ProvinceId = p.ID
    for json path
    ) as districts
from province p
for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

Only problem is that SQL Server doesn't support pure arrays in JSON for some reason, otherwise you should be good to go.
One important wrinkle is that JSON_QUERY is needed to convert the "pseudo"-json array to a real JSON field. This is mostly SQL Server goo, otherwise it thinks the array is pure string, and will try to escape it, which we don't want.

this answer is good but if there's no data in wards then it doesn't return in district lists
it looks like this
[{"id": 1, "name": "name 1", "wards": [1,2,3]}, {"id": 2, "name": "name 2"}]

Is that good or bad? You can always isnull(..., '[]') if that is a problem for you

good is it returns json what I expect, and bad is some object returns as expect but some doesn't which I mentioned above. so where can I use isnull function in your query

You should be able to figure it out. I'd put it inside the JSON_QUERY

This is impossible for demonstrate for the OP's data, as we don't have any. I've therefore used some sys objects to demonstrate how to:

Nest JSON value
Emulate JSON_ARRAYAGG, as it's not available outside of Preview.

JSON nesting is done just like XML nesting, with sub queries. For aggregating the values into an array, then one with is to still using STRING_AGG, however, we'll then need to use JSON_QUERY to turn that into actual JSON, rather than a literal. This results in something like the following:
SELECT s.name AS schema_name,
       (SELECT object_id,
              name,
              JSON_QUERY((SELECT CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(c.column_id,','),']')
                          FROM sys.columns c
                          WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id),'$') AS column_ids
         FROM sys.tables t
         WHERE t.schema_id = s.schema_id
         FOR JSON AUTO) AS tables
FROM sys.schemas s
FOR JSON AUTO;

And that gives a result like this:
[
    {
        "schema_name": "dbo"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "guest"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "sys"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "fn"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "sp"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "t"
    },
    {
        "schema_name": "tbl",
        "tables": [
            {
                "object_id": 389576426,
                "name": "Calendar",
                "column_ids": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5,
                    6,
                    7,
                    8
                ]
            },
            {
                "object_id": 1618104805,
                "name": "Clock",
                "column_ids": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

If you are dealing with strings, then you will need to also quote the value, and likely want to use something like STRING_ESCAPE to ensure that certain characters are escaped appropriately:
CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(YourColumn) + '"',','),']')


You can pre-group ward.Id, as shown in Cte.
Or use cross apply with concatenated ward.id's
See example
declare @id int =1;

with wardList as(
  select d.Id as DistrictId,string_agg(w.id,',') wList
  from district d
  left join ward w on w.DistrictId=d.Id
  where d.ProvinceId=@id
  group by d.id
)
select CONCAT(
    '{"id":"', p.[id], '"',
    ',"province_name":', max(p.Name),
    ',"districts":',
    CONCAT(
    '[{',
    STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT('"id":', CAST(d.Id AS VARCHAR(10)),
        ',"district_name":"', d.Name,
        '","wards":[', wList, ']'), '},{'),
    '}]'),
    '}')
from province p
left join district d on d.provinceId = p.id
left join wardList w on w.DistrictId = d.id
where p.id = @id
group by P.ID

Result is
{"id":"1","province_name":Province1,
   "districts":[
           {"id":1,"district_name":"P1District1","wards":[1,2,3]}, 
           {"id":2,"district_name":"P1District2","wards":[4,5,6]}, 
           {"id":3,"district_name":"P1District3","wards":[]}
      ]
}

Similar query
select CONCAT(
    '{"id":"', p.[id], '"',
    ',"province_name":', max(p.Name),
    ',"districts":',
    CONCAT(
    '[{',
    STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT('"id":', CAST(d.Id AS VARCHAR(10)),
        ',"district_name":"', d.Name,
        '","wards":[', wList, ']'), '},{'),
    '}]'),
    '}')
from province p
left join district d on d.provinceId = p.id
cross apply (
 select string_agg(w.id,',') wList
  from district d2
  left join ward w on w.DistrictId=d.Id 
  where d2.ProvinceId=p.id and w.DistrictId=d2.Id
  group by d2.id
 ) wardList 
where p.id = @id
group by P.ID

Output is
{"id":"1","province_name":Province1
    ,"districts":[
      {"id":1,"district_name":"P1District1","wards":[1,2,3]},
      {"id":2,"district_name":"P1District2","wards":[4,5,6]}
    ]
}

With test data
insert into Province values 
 (1,'Province1')
,(2,'Province1')
insert into District values 
 (1, 'P1District1', 1)
,(2, 'P1District2', 1)
,(3, 'P1District3', 1)
,(4, 'P2District1', 2)
;
insert into Ward values 
 (1, 'P1D1Ward1', 1)
,(2, 'P1D1Ward2', 1)
,(3, 'P1D1Ward3', 1)
,(4, 'P1D2Ward1', 2)
,(5, 'P1D2Ward2', 2)
,(6, 'P1D2Ward3', 2)
;

fiddle
